# What's the best random number generator for android?

Tags: android, random, google-play

There are many generators out there, but none completely suits me. First of all, we need a simple one, with a good design, convenient and with wide functionality.

Comment: Please state what you want clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mch.pavel.randomizer
This is the best of all. I use it almost every day. No freezes or errors, cool interface, everything is intuitive.

Comment: Thank you, this one is very cool